# ruby on rails undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby

currently working on my project.and
i'm trying to create an existing article page but i keep getting this message
    undefined method `errors' for nil: Nil Class. currently working on my project
    Edit existing article

```
<% if@article.errors.any? %>
<h>The following errors prevented the article from getting created</h>
<ul>
<%@article.errors.full_messages.each do  |msg| %
```

Comment: You have to define `@article` in your controller.

Answer (score 1):

`@article` doesn't exist. It's probably expected that your controller is setting this variable, and you haven't done that (or it's failing to get a value for some other reason).

Note that the places `errors` exists in your code snippet are method calls (`x.y` implies `y` is a method on the object `x` in Ruby). This is how to identify this problem in the future.